# Device Can't Power Down

Tags: boot, stock-android

I have an Android device which had a custom os..It was for educational purposes and I could not even open another app on it. After the end of the subscription period I thought of using the device. I tried opening it's recovery mode but instead opened some factory or diagnostic mode which was in Chinese. By mistake I pressed the power key to select an option ending with "emmc" and now It boots but shows a black screen with navigation buttons and time...Any keys pressed make no effect and I am unable to shut it down. When I press the power key for a few seconds it reboots but shows the same screen. I just want to shut it down somehow. Please Help!!

**Edit**: I found a way to shut my phone down. I connect it to my pc and then press the power button for 10 seconds then the screen goes off and the charging percentage shows up after a couple of seconds, I pull the usb cable out and the screen disappears and voila ! My phone is switched off.

Thanks for all your response.

Comment: Seems like a clone... What phone is that?

Comment: It is a tablet : Lenovo tab 2 A7-10

Answer (score -2):

Just pull off and reinsert the battery.

Comment: -1: you shouldn't presume that the battery be removable, without knowing the device model.

Comment: Correct. The battery is non-removable

Comment: Thank you guys for admiring my effort to help - you too kind. And, by the way, suggesting something so probable is a good way to save time. It's not like there's many options - battery is either removable or not so it was wise not to specify that first. Because as result, there are only one my comment posted instead of two or  three.

Comment: And, after all, you can always try to reboot your phone continuously for battery to get empty more quickly or, which is more likely option - just leave your phone turned on for night. But I'm not sure if this will help after all. You can try it still since there's​ not much of options available.