# How to get Lenovo Stock Rom

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, stock-android

I had asked this question...
[My Previous Question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/174076/218990%22Link%20To%20My%20Previous%20Question)

Good News is that somehow I am able to put my tab in recovery mode. I wanted to install the stock lollipop version of Android in it and after doing some research I found this link...[Link to Lenovo Website](http://pcsupport.lenovo.com/in/en/products/tablets/a-series/a7-10-2/downloads/ds105762)
But I am unable to understand that how can I put this in my device. So my question is can any of you provide me guidance on how to install this on my device or atleast can provide me a link to a flashable stock ROM. Any help would be appreciated

**Edit**: Okay, So I finally got it up and running, but I have a small problem that I can't enter it's recovery mode through the previously correct key combination. It just shows Lenovo's splash screen. I can however use:

> adb reboot recovery

Can Anybody help me with this please?

Comment: Which Lenovo tablet model is yours?

Comment: The link you found is the source code (for developers), not a ROM.

Comment: What button combos you were performing to enter the recovery?

Comment: Vol + , Vol-, Power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading from your previous question, the model is  `Lenovo tab 2 A7-10`which has a Mediatek chipset (Mediatek MT8127). 
So you need SP Flashtool and the firmware with a scatter file to be able to flash your device.

1. [SP Flashtool](http://spflashtool.com/) (Download and unzip then run it)
2. [Stock firmware](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6QqD/uhafte3xz) or [Mirror](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/CREh/skZMSYmmZ) - password: *lenovo-forums.ru* (Download and unzip)
3. [MTK VCOM, CDC Drivers](https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-usb-all-drivers) or [Mirror](http://mtkusballdriver.com/wp-content/uploads/MTK_USB_All_v1.0.1.zip) (Download and install)

Install the drivers for the computer to be able to detect the device. 
Power down your device. If you can't, just force shut it down (Keep pressing Power button + volume down button for a couple of seconds).

On SP Flashtool, click on Scatter-Loading: Browse to the folder where you unzipped the firmware, you'll find a text file similar to this: `MTXXXX_Android_scatter.txt`. select it.

You'll be back in the SP Flashtool interface, uncheck the first field (Preloader) and leave the other checked.

Click on Download (green arrow) and wait the software do its things. You should get a big green checkmark if everything goes fine.

Please comment with any errors occurred. I'll update my answer with new elements.

Comment: BTW why do I have do uncheck Preloader? Can't I just install a new Preloader?

Comment: It is not recommended to flash the preloader because even if the flash file is correct, the preloader may be different. flashing a wrong preloader simply kills your phone.

Comment: Should be simply with Volume up + Power button

Comment: Actually, This vol+, Power combination lands me into the same test menu I mentioned in my previous question

Comment: Well, holding volume up + volume down + power should take you to recovery menu, weird this doesn't work, or may be on of your​ volume buttons is broken?... `adb reboot recovery` should work if you enable USB debugging from the developer menu

Comment: No. My volume buttons are alright. Anyways it does not matter anymore because I have rooted my device and installed xposed framework and I use one of its modules to add a recovery option in my power menu which reboots to TWRP (which I installed earlier).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following method. This is the convectional way of installing/upgrading firmware on most android devices:

- Download official firmware (correct version) preferably on PC. Extract the download you should see a **sdfuse folder**

Depending on contents of the compressed file you may not find the sdfuse folder, in this case;

- create a folder in your external sdcard and rename it as sdfuse
- extract firmware zip and copy qsb firmware "the file vit extension .qsb" to sdfuse folder or it may have the .inb extension.

  - You will need to transfer **sdfuse folder** preferably using a micro sd card Adapter or card reader from the PC  to the phone.
  - Make sure phone is off completely. Then press and HOLD the POWER+VOLUME DOWN buttons simultaneously until the **service menu** appears.
  - Using your Vol+/Vol- buttons navigate to **sd update** and the installation should begin. Follow the instructions carefully to successfully re-install the firmware.

(*Your phone must have at least 50-80% of battery charged* )

Credits:

1. [Lenovo S60-A Flash File (Stock ROM) zip](http://supergeekforum.org/lenovo-s60-a-flash-file-stock-rom-zip)

Answer (score 0):

Files you need to download to your computer.

[Download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/daw4659azkxvf2f/Lenovo_IdeaPad_A7-10F_MT8127_20150322.zip) Lenovo Tab 2 A7-10F ROM or other [Lenovo stock ROM](https://www.androidflashtools.com/list-of-lenovo-stock-roms/).[Download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/64p99b0e7hqskik/SP_Flash_Tool_v5.1728_Win.zip) SP Flash Tool.
[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B69b11bY5owSUGhFQzFlUmJvMTQ/view) Universal ADB Driver Sedboz. 
[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B69b11bY5owSNkhMcS1iaExpQkk/view?usp=drive_web) ADB Installer.

### How to install stock ROM on Lenovo Tab 2 A7-10F?

1. Open SP Flash Tools then install on your PC.
2. Now click on Scatter Loading on SP Flash Tool.  Choose the Scatter file you downloaded earlier on your computer.
3. SP Flash Tool will load the Scatter file you have selected.  Now click the Download button on SP Flash Tool.
4. Remove your Lenovo tablet's battery if it's removable or if not just
5. Power It Off then press UP button.  Connect your Lenovo tablet to PC using the USB data cable then put your Lenovo tablet's battery back to its place while your finger pressing Volume UP (+) and this action    will automatically start the firmware flashing processes on your    Lenovo tablet immediately right now.
6. Wait the firmware flashing to    get completed.  If you see the round green notification shows up on    the SP Flash Tool that means the firmware flashing processes are    complete.  You may disconnect your Lenovo tablet from USB data cable    now and remove your battery afterward then put it back again right.
7. Now Turn On your device guys.
8. Well done.